# how to reduce line height of a table row

Tags: html, css

I wanna reduce the line height between table rows. I used the following code, But it didn't work for me. Please look at my picture. I wanna reduce the line height between **"Mon-Sat 09:00 AM - 7:00 PM"** and
**"We closed Sunday & Holidays"**. see the photo
[image]

I used following code, But I didn't do anything

```css
.tb tr {
  height: 0px;
}

table {
  margin: 0 15.0% 0 0;
  float: right;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="tb">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Business Hours:</p>
    </td>
    <td><span>Mon - Sat 09:00AM - 7:00PM</span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><span>We closed Sunday & Holidays</span> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please tell me how to do it.. default table height is very high.

Comment: Your selector is looking for a `tb` tag containing a `tr` tag. There is no `tb`. To target a class you need to use `.` eg: `.tb tr`

Comment: oh sorry. it is editing error,, but adding . is not get my expected results

Comment: @JonP it is only increasing heigh, Not reduce height

Comment: Note the `table` tag is meant for tabular data **only** . If you are using it for layout, you're using it wrong. The exception to this is HTML emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p` tag has margin at top and bottom from the browser css. Please just add the below condition and adjust the margins to your desired height!

```css
.tb tr {
  height: 0px;
}

p.bottom-no-space {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table class="tb" style="margin:0 15.0% 0 0; float: right;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p style="font-weight: bold;  float: right;" class="bottom-no-space">Business Hours:</p>
    </td>
    <td><span style="font-weight: bold; color: red; ">Mon - Sat 09:00AM - 7:00PM</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><span style="font-weight: bold;color: red; ">We closed Sunday & Holidays</span> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: code is working , But this code doesn't do anything .

Comment: @SupunMadhushanka what is it lacking, what is it missing?

Comment: i add following code to css file but nothing happened. I tried your code from separately.It is working. But it is not working in my html css file `p.bottom-no-space {
  margin: 0px;
}`

Comment: @SupunMadhushanka did you add the class like `<p class="bottom-no-space">`, if this also doesnt work, please go for `margin: 0px !important;` in the css

Comment: there are a lot of p tags on this html page. I think it is the error

Comment: @SupunMadhushanka Please try `tb p {margin: 0px !important;` inside css. Inside the table with class `tb` it will set margin to 0 for all the p tags!

Comment: The `p` tags are probably not required at all. Just at the style to the `td` or better still use a class. Same with the `spans`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily manipulate HTML tables with css using the ff.

```
/*if you want your table to have borders*/
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/*If you want your borders to be merged to other borders*/
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

/*Finally the height, this will give your th, td and tr an equal height of 0px
 just try to play with this to get your desired height, you can also use padding*/
th, td, tr {
  height: 0px;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table_size.asp

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `table`. You can lay this out with much more flexibility with out. There are many ways to do this. Just one example is below. A definition list would also be a good candidate here.

```css
.businessHours * {font-size:16px;}
.businessHours h1 {margin: 0; padding-right:1em;}
.businessHours {display:flex; align-itmes:flex-start;}
.businessHours > div {color:red; font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<section class="businessHours">
<h1>Business Hours</h1>
<div>
  <div>Mon - Sun 0:900AM - 7:00PM</div>
  <div>We are closed Sundsays & Holidays</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: your code is gave me this  [see this photo](https://i.postimg.cc/BnGYtz5F/2022-07-15-09-49-12-Window.jpg) I want this same column, Mon-saturday and We are closed should be same column

Comment: There are no columns as such. The M-s and Closed text are in the same container. It looks like you have a `text-align:center` somewhere in your code to give that result. Running the code in the snippet above gives the result you are after. You shoiuld you the developer tools in your browser to see what in your code is causing the issue.